# Oracle PL SQL Code to SQL Server T-SQL Code conversion

Tags: sql-server, oracle, code-conversion

Can someone please help me point to a tested repository which will have Oracle as well as SQL Server versions of the same code (procedures/functions)? I need some examples which cover some of the core differences and have been tested for accuracy. Thanks a ton!!

If not a repository, any website I can refer to with some sample codes?